# Книга в формате Jar

Tags: jar, книги

Есть книга в формате Jar (сколько не искал, в другом формате не нашел), книга создана с помощью Sebook, внутри находятся пару файлов class и 20 файлов без расширения (бинарные).

Может, кто подскажет, как из такой книги можно вытащить текст (попытался окрыть эмулятором, но с его помощь нельзя текст копировать, только читать)?

Answer (score 1):

Откройте эти бинары любым текстовым  редактором скопируйте текст в пустой текстовый документ и сохраните. Книга готова.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?